# Dynamic required field in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

How to make a text item into required field, dynamically using jquery. I want to fire this from a dynamic action. I tried this code

```
$('#P17_MCODE').prop('required',true);
```

But it didn't worked. How to do this in oracle apex?

Comment: What sort of behaviour are you expecting to change? Visibility? Validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#P17_MCODE').attr("required", "true");
```

i think this will work,.

Comment: I tried this too.. but not working for me. When I inspected the code of a required field element I could see some classes added to  required field elements. it was added inside the <span>. So I need to add the code        <span class="t-Form-required" ><span class="a-Icon icon-asterisk">::before </span></span>         dynamically. It has to be added next to item label, which are child of class t-Form-labelContainer col col-2. So I am working on it. I will be thankful if you can help.

Comment: what is the use of adding class t-Form-required to a span?